# Problem with Showing data in a table. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created feature for show 1 column of table and 1 column checkbox (for every row should be checkbox). I added this file in a folder component. What was my goal: I will have a page, user will choose account type and after that I will return him new table based on his choose.

Now I created special component for my page "Account type" - here I get accounts type. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Spin } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useFetch } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';

const AccountType = ({ onSelectingItems }) => {
  const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.getAccountType);

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <Table
        key="id"
        bordered="true"
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ onChange: onSelectingItems }}
        pagination={false}
      >
        <Table.Column title="Account Type" dataIndex="accountType" />
      </Table>
    </Spin>
  );
};

AccountType.propTypes = {
  onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
};

AccountType.defaultProps = {
  onSelectingItems: () => { },
};

export default AccountType;
```

After that I started create a page from where I will call this component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Spin } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useFetch } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';
import AccountType from 'components/AccountType';

const MoveProperty = ({ onSelectingItems }) => {
  const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.moveProperty);
  const [setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <AccountType onSelectingItems={setSelectedItems} />
      <Table
        key="id"
        bordered="true"
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ onChange: onSelectingItems }}
        pagination={false}
      >
        <Table.Column title="Account Type" dataIndex="accountType" />
        <Table.Column title="Account Number" dataIndex="accountNumber" />
        <Table.Column title="Account ID" dataIndex="accountId" />
        <Table.Column title="Account Name" dataIndex="accountName" />
      </Table>
    </Spin>
  );
};

MoveProperty.propTypes = {
  onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
};

MoveProperty.defaultProps = {
  onSelectingItems: () => { },
};

export default MoveProperty;
```

Now feature works good. But in 1st table I don't have a data. But as I understand it should be here. API works good. I think problem could be in a calling Account Type feature. Where did I error?

Attached screen. It is my next mistake that I didn't do space between tables. Here I planned add button and after user will click - user will see next table. Based on his choice.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you fetch by different methods - `apiService.getAccountType` && `apiService.moveProperty`

what shape of response in `useFetch(apiService.getAccountType)`?

as I understand `const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.getAccountType);` `data` doesn't have field `accountType`

Comment: **1)** Yeah it is different methods. It's required for my feature.
 
**2)** If I correctly understand your question - here will return from Backend several account Types (id+ name)

**3)** How could  I change it correctly?

Comment: `id+ name` but your table wait for `accountType` you should do

`data.map(({id, name }) => ({id, accountType: name }))`